# Use of System date and user-input date in Windows VS Mac

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have been using this piece of code on my PC running windows and Excel 2013 to return a date.

As shown in the code, the systems prompts for the use of current system date VS use of user-input date.

```
Function GetRegDate() As Date
Dim RegToday As String

RegToday = MsgBox("Are the transaction(s) of today (System time)?",vbYesNo)

If RegToday = vbYes Then
        ' Use Current System Date
        GetRegDate = Date
    Else
        ' Use user-input date
        Dim RegYear, RegMonth, RegDay As Long
            RegYear = InputBox("Please enter the year of the transaction.")
            RegMonth = InputBox("Please enter the month of the transaction (in number).")
            RegDay = InputBox("Please enter the day of the transaction.")
            GetRegDate = RegDay & "/" & RegMonth & "/" & RegYear
End If

' Some other codes
End Function
```

The piece of code has been consistently successful on my PC. But it isn't the case when my friend uses it on his Mac running Excel 2011.

Taking 26 Mar 2016 As an example, on my PC, by using the current system date or the user-input date method, the value "#26/3/2016#" is stored in the variable 'GetRegDate', as reflected from the local variable windows.
But as my friend told me, when using current system date, the value "##" is stored. When using the user-input date method, an error occurs at the line

```
GetRegDate = RegDay & "/" & RegMonth & "/" & RegYear
```

with the runtime error 13 type mismatch

I have no idea why this happened. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm using Excel 2011 Version 14.2.3 Build 120616 and your code runs perfectly fine. Both `Date` and the `Input` methods work as expected. Did they open a brand new workbook, paste it in and go, or did they use your existing workbook?

Comment: He used a workbook that I provided, with the code already inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug.  From [Microsoft Communities](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/vba-for-excel-2011-no-longer-handling-dates-since/3d04e3b6-3cbc-4a36-89e8-323de4f1c7d1):

> This is known bug with some of the region settings, working OK when
>   you use the Dutch region but not for example when you use the French
>   settings
>
> Got one user that fix it by running this in the Terminal window
>
> defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleICUDateFormatStrings -dict 1
>   dd/MM/yy
>
> I hope they fix it soon

That said, you shouldn't implicitly cast to a Date with `GetRegDate = RegDay & "/" & RegMonth & "/" & RegYear`. Use `DateSerial` to avoid region issues:

```
GetRegDate = DateSerial(RegYear, RegMonth, RegDay)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have tested this on my PC and it works and have told my friend to try it out. But what about the line “GetRegDate = Date”? What can't this return the system's date on my friend's MacBook? According to the information in this page: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/date_vba.php I thought this should work with Excel 2011 on Mac

Comment: It should return the system date, but my best guess is it also has something to do with the region settings.

Comment: My friend has tested using DateSerial, but still, "##" instead of a proper date like "#28/3/2016#" is stored in the variable... Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MatthewHui - Unfortunately I don't have a test environment to examine this much further. You can test to see if it's just a formatting issue with `Debug.Print CDbl(Date)` - it should output 42456 (if you do it today obviously).

Comment: Thanks for the help all along. It is not solved yet though. But I think I have now focused the problem: nothing can be store in a variable declared as date in various ways. I think I will create a new thread for this.